# localization with core data

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, localization, internationalization

Does anyone have any recommendations with localization of core data? My application will have information that will sometimes be the same in both langauges, such as a person's photo, or different such as the person's biography.

From what I understand, it's possible to [localize the field names](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005190-SW13), but what's the best course of action for field values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to localize string values, you should create an entity named something like LocalizableText with attributes locale and localizedText. Instead of using NSStrings for your attributes, you will instead have a relationship to LocalizableText.

So your Person entity would have a relationship named biography to entity LocalizableText. It would also have a read-only property for localizedBiography which would check for the appropriate localizedText to return based on the current locale of your user.

Comment: Hey thanks. Perhaps this is my inexperience, but I'm not sure why you would do it that way. Do you have a guide/doc that talks about that strategy? Right now I'm considering just have an biography_english and biography_french in the same table. Is there a reason why I shouldnt?

Comment: Well, it depends on your usage. If you know you will never localize for another language, and the chances of needing translation for other fields at some point in the future, then adding language specific fields is okay. However, making a generic entity that you can use for any translated field and with any language will make your life easier when you decide you want to localize other field or for other languages.

Comment: Also, it's easier to call the localizedText attribute on the entity for the UI field than have to re-do every field mapping on your UI for each language. Basically think of it as a fancier version of an NSString attribute.

Comment: Is there any way to leverage Core Data sorting with this approach though? My understanding is that Core Data would not be able to sort on the localizedBiography property.